# Comment dit-on : « I am/was joking » ?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

Est-ce qu'il y a une ou plusieurs expressions équivalentes à l'anglais « I am/was joking » ?

Comment: Qu'ont donné tes recherches ? as-tu quelque chose à proposer ?

Comment: Pour ce genre de recherche, utilise linguee : http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=I+am+joking+ , très utile pour connaître les formulations couramment utilisé, et celles spécifiques à un domaine donné.

Comment: @cl-r Je voudrais ajouter qu'il faut prendre soin lorsqu'on utilise linguee, particulièrement lorsqu'on est un débutant. Il faut faire attention aux liens au-dessous les traductions pour vérifier la région et la validité. Je dirais que les sites gouvernementaux sont les plus utiles et standardisés.

Comment: En effet, de plus si *linguee* est bien un outil formidable, il a cependant un pré-requis assez lourd : il faut déjà connaître (au moins en partie) les deux langages impliqués, ou risquer une traduction potentiellement catastrophique, pire encore que les googleries les plus maladroites...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On peut dire (du plus soutenu au plus familier IMHO) :

- *Je **plaisante*** (courant - soutenu)
- *On [te] **taquine*** (courant - soutenu)
- *C'est juste **pour rire*** (courant)
- *C'est juste **pour s'amuser*** (courant)
- *On **rigole*** (familier)
- *Je **blague*** (familier)
- Je [te] **charrie** (familier)
- *C'est une **vanne*** (familier)
- *Je **déconne*** (familier voir argot suivant le contexte, le public et le pays)

Pour certains des mots clefs en gras il y a des variations possible au niveau du temps et de la construction de la phrase :

- On(je) rigole
- On(je) rigolait(s)
- C'était(c'est) [juste] pour rigoler

Comment: C'est juste pour rire. C'est juste pour s'amuser.
C'est une vanne.

Comment: @Laure j'ai ajouté tes suggestions

Comment: (même commentaire que pour la réponse de Kraiss à propos de *Je déconne*.) J'imagine mal une personne de moins de 30 ans utiliser autre chose que *Je rigolais* ou *je déconnais* (voire *C'était une vanne*) à moins d'être dans un contexte extrêmement hostile. Excellente réponse au demeurant (+1).

Comment: @RomainVALERI le mot **très** est peut-être un peu fort en effet. J'ai essayé de les classer du plus soutenu au plus familier mais c'est quelque chose d'assez subjectif :/

Comment: **Je déconne** est de l'argot, et donc plutôt vulgaire que familier.

Comment: Au Québec, je déconne n'est clairement pas considéré vulgaire (en fait, ça m'a fait sourire de lire ça :)

Comment: _Je (te) charrie_.

Answer (score 6):

Au Québec, dans le langage parlé, il est très courant d'entendre:

- C'tune joke
- Je niaise

En plus des expressions plus classiques telles que:

- Je blague
- Je rigole
- Je plaisante
- Je te taquine
- Je déconne

À noter que l'expression suivante n'est pas utilisée au Québec:

- C'est une vanne

Answer (score 2):

Oui, les plus courantes étant "Je plaisantais" (correct) ou "je déconnais" (familier)

Comment: Je me suis permis de qualifier les réponses, c'est nécessaire pour ceux qui découvrent la francophonie.

Comment: *très familier* me semble trop fort. *familier*, oui, mais ni grossier ni particulièrement offensant. Comme tous les autres termes familiers, à éviter avec des inconnus ou dans les contextes les plus formels.

Comment: Il me semble que conseiller de dire "je déconnais" est dangereux : cela frise la grossièreté. J'aime assez le "populaire" employé par wiktionnary qui le distingue de familier qu'il prête à "pote" par exemple.

Comment: La "grossierté" ? Je suis français et je peux t'assurer que ça n'a rien de grossier. C'est certes "populaire" mais ça n'est pas "grossier". Personnellement je pense que "familier" est très adapté.